# How to create a core data manager environment in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

I am rather new to SwiftUI and Core Data. I learned about Observable Objects that I can use as an environment object to load my data only once and make it available for every view.
There, I had a class that conformed to `ObservableObject` and I could publish my local variables / data.

Now, that I learned Core Data, I am wondering, how I could do something familiar.
When I create my entities and relations, I get something linke this:

```
extension Foo {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Foo> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Foo>(entityName: "Foo")
    }

    @NSManaged public var name: String
    @NSManaged public var date: Date
    @NSManaged public var bars: NSSet
    
    public var barsArray: [Bar] {
        let set = bars as? Set<Bar> ?? []
        return Array(set)
    }

}
```

I created the `barsArray` to work with arrays.
Within my views, every time I need a core data entity, I call:

```
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Foo.date, ascending: false)]) var foos: FetchedResults<Foo>
```

My question is, how can I create a Cora Data Manager Class (?) to have my data available like in Observable Objects. Or is there something even better / easier?

To give more like a real world problem: I have a entity with categories and in man views of my app, I call the fetch request to get access to the categories. But it makes sense, to load them only once and pass it to the required views and the question is: how? Hope, this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to use `@FetchRequest` once in the MainView and then pass your entities to your subviews.

Let say you have your FetchRequest in your ListView:

```
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Foo.date, ascending: false)]) var foos: FetchedResults<Foo>
```

Then in the List, iterate over all elements and pass them to your Subview as a ObservedObject.

List
{
ForEach(self.foos, id:.self) { foo in
DetailView(item: foo)
}

And in your DetailView, declare Foo as ObservedObject, which will get passed from parent view. As it is `ObservedObject`, it will automatically detect changes and updates your view.

```
struct DetailView : View 
{
    @ObservedObject var foo : Foo
```

FetchRequest is one of the great features, which makes SwiftUI and CoreData really great in my View. Whenever you create a new entity, FetchRequest will update immediately.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply. Your answer is what I already have. I want to move the FetchRequest out of the "ListView", because I have multiple ListViews that access the fetch request. Let's say "one level higher".

Comment: There is nothing wrong with having the FetchRequest duplicated in multiple views, at least if you don't do any intensive post processing when new data has been fetched.